# How to get rid of the square dot in front of a heading in microsoft word

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, office365

Suppose we  have an article with sections and subsections, with section titles in the format

> 1.3.5. Section title

I put those text in "title" style (as described in [this webpage](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/apply-styles-f8b96097-4d25-4fac-8200-6139c8093109)). Then I discover a square black dot in front of the title:
[image]

**How could I get rid of the dot in front of H?**

This dot only appears on windows computers. It does not seem to appear on Mac.

Comment: That looks like a bullet list to me. Try highlighting it and then going to the Styles menu and see if bullet list is selected.

Comment: @bashBedlam No. No bullet list selected. And it only appear on the windows version of word. It is a numbered list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can eliminate this little black dot in the following way：

Right-click the title format you are using and select modify

[image]

Select “paragraph” in the lower left corner of the pop-up window and uncheck these options: 1.keep with next 2. keep lines together

[image]

Comment: Thank you very very very much!!!!!

Comment: If they are section titles, you should leave "Keep with next" applied so that it stays with the following text (ie with editing, you don't want to end up with heading orphaned at bottom of a page and relevant text then at top of next page).  You can change the view so that you don't see any formatting marks on screen by instead pressing CTRL SHIFT 8 (or change your Word options for formatting marks re Display options for Word, if you want to see some but not all eg tabs and spaces and paragraph marks).